# Europe Etiquette : Should I reply to a reply?

Tags: etiquette, email, answering-questions

When asking a question to a professor, I wonder if I should reply to his answer if I have no other questions with "Thank you for your kind answer professor". I guess this is the polite thing to do but with covid-19, I know professors are overwhelmed with mails from student and I am wondering if I am expected to systematically thank them for their replies to my questions or does it just bother them with extra-mails in their mailbox ?
Also, I am in a master student in an European university where there is a high hierarchical gap between students and professors.

Comment: You're overthinking this.

Comment: a good rule of thumb is that professors are people

Comment: It is very unlikely that they will bear a grudge against you for sending them an email, but very likely that they will appreciate a "thank you" message which acknowledges their response.

Comment: Thank you for all your answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm here in the US, so I can't speak to how things work in Europe.  But here, I get lots of emails that require answers, which often take time.  When a student says, thank you but doesn't require any further response, I appreciate it.  YMMV.

Comment: Thank  you for your answers !